# Zeros in contingency table for fisher's exact test for data drift detection

Tags: hypothesis-testing, goodness-of-fit, fishers-exact-test, data-drift

**Background**

I'm trying to use fisher's exact test for to measure data-drift detection between two features. The usecase is , I can retrain my model if the data has drifted. I'm trying to use fisher's test as I found out that it is able to handle low cell counts where chi-square assumptions fail.
I'm using `scipy.stats.fisher_exact` to compute the pvalue.

I have the below contingency tables and reference and
current data

#######################################################

```
reference = ["a"]*25
current = ["a"]*25  
2x2 table = [[25, 0],
             [0, 0]]
```

#######################################################

```
reference = ["a"]*25
current = ["b"]*25  
2x2 table = [[0, 25],
             [0, 0]]
```

#######################################################

```
reference = ["b"]*25
current = ["a"]*25  
2x2 table = [[0, 0],
             [25, 0]]
```

#######################################################

```
reference = ["a", "a","b","b"]
current = ["b", "b","a","a"]
2x2 table = [[0, 2],
             [2, 0]]
```

#######################################################

```
reference = ["a", "a","b","b"]
current= ["a", "a","b","b"]
2x2 table = [[2, 0],
             [0, 2]]
```

########################################################

In Some of the above cases the `current` is `reference` flipped, in that case
there should be a drift detected. But fisher exact is giving me a `pvalue of 1` and
also the `odds ratio` is `NaN or inf`

Can you please tell me how can I use fisher's exact test to detect drift on the above scenarios as `scipy.stats.fisher_exact` is reporting a `pvalue of 1`
Or is should I be using something else ?

I did go through other zero in data/ contingency table issues on this stats.stackexchange
couldn't find one on drift detection, hence I posted it.

Comment: Please explain what exactly goes into the cells of the contingency tables and how this is connected with `reference` and `current`.

Comment: Hi, 
The contingency table contains the count of reference and current 

eg: 
reference = [ 1, 1, 1, 1]
current = [0, 0, 0, 0]
So I get the counts are { (0,0) = 0,  (1,0) = 4 , (0,1) = 0, (1,1) = 0 }

This goes into contingency table as  
[ [0, 0],
  [4, 0] ]
and then I use this to calculate fishers exact.

Comment: not sure it really makes sense to do a test when one of your margins is zero. in this case it makes sense that the p-value is one. (if you don't have any observations of one of the groups, you have nothing to test.)

Comment: This doesn't explain your first example. Also, it's easier for others if you update your question.

Comment: @frank Thanks, I've corrected the mistake I made in the question, what would you suggest to update the question as?

Comment: @wzbillings  What would you suggest I do for these cases to detect drift ?  hamming distance or something else ?

Comment: Can you say more about the circumstances in which you are doing this data drift detection? From the examples, it seem that there are many zeros because you are analyzing a very small number of items. The right outcome of such analysis is very likely "not enough data", i.e. a large p-value.

Comment: @jayeez you shouldn't do anything else. you don't have enough information to detect drift because you haven't observed an entire category. It seems unlikely to come up in a real life situation, but if it does, not having enough information (i.e. a large p-value) as dipetkov mentioned is the correct outcome.